# D3 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…"

Tags: d3.js

I have a feeling that the issue is with the order_date format.

All the logs through the area function work but it doesn't render and when I check the console, I get `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…"`

If I comment out the `.attr('d', area)` no errors.

This is also on jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/walkerl/8uxrxm0k/3/)

```js
const rawData = [{
    "agency_id": 541,
    "agency_name": "Store1",
    "order_date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "store_name": "Store1",
    "store_id": 1469,
    "orders": 3,
    "avg_order_size": 2,
    "revenue": 500
  },
  {
    "agency_id": 541,
    "agency_name": "Store2",
    "order_date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "store_name": "Store2",
    "store_id": 1468,
    "orders": 2,
    "avg_order_size": 1,
    "revenue": 81
  },
  {
    "agency_id": 541,
    "agency_name": "Store3",
    "order_date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "store_name": "Store3",
    "store_id": 1404,
    "orders": 14,
    "avg_order_size": 1,
    "revenue": 1348.26
  },
  {
    "agency_id": 541,
    "agency_name": "Store4",
    "order_date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "store_name": "Store4",
    "store_id": 1517,
    "orders": 41,
    "avg_order_size": 1,
    "revenue": 8115.6
  },
  {
    "agency_id": 541,
    "agency_name": "Store1",
    "order_date": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "store_name": "Store1",
    "store_id": 1469,
    "orders": 7,
    "avg_order_size": 1,
    "revenue": 1522
  },
  {
    "agency_id": 541,
    "agency_name": "Store2",
    "order_date": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "store_name": "Store2",
    "store_id": 1468,
    "orders": 3,
    "avg_order_size": 2,
    "revenue": 297.5
  },
  {
    "agency_id": 541,
    "agency_name": "Store3",
    "order_date": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "store_name": "Store3",
    "store_id": 1404,
    "orders": 14,
    "avg_order_size": 2,
    "revenue": 1515.76
  },
  {
    "agency_id": 541,
    "agency_name": "Store4",
    "order_date": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "store_name": "Store4",
    "store_id": 1517,
    "orders": 40,
    "avg_order_size": 1,
    "revenue": 7288.8
  }
];

/**
const cleanData = [
  {
    "order_date": "2017-12-31",
    "Store1": 500,
    "Store2": 81,
    "Store3": 1348.26,
    "Store4": 8115.6
  },
  {
    "order_date": "2018-01-01",
    "Store1": 1522,
    "Store2": 297.5,
    "Store3": 1515.76,
    "Store4": 7288.8
  }
]
*/


const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
const formatTime = d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ');
const p = d3.precisionFixed('.01');
const formatNumber = d3.format(`.${p}f`);
const stores = rawData
  .map(d => ({
    name: d.store_name,
    id: d.store_id
  }))
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc.find(s => s.id === cur.id) ? acc : [...acc, cur], []);
const storeNames = stores.map(s => s.name)

// This is to group the data as objects with the date and revenue for each store.  Also, the date has to be a js object
const stackData = rawData
  .map(d => ({ ...d,
    order_date: formatTime(new Date(d.order_date)),
    revenue: formatNumber(d.revenue)
  }))
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    let existing = acc.find(e => e.order_date === cur.order_date)
    if (existing) {
      existing[cur.store_name] = cur.revenue;
      return acc
    }
    return [...acc, {
      order_date: cur.order_date,
      [cur.store_name]: cur.revenue
    }]
  }, []);

const margin = {
  top: 50,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 70,
  left: 50
};
const width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left;
const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePastel1);

let g = d3.select('#stacked-area')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

let x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, width])

let y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

let xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom();
let yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft();

let xAxisGroup = g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)

let yAxisGroup = g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')


let stack = d3.stack()
  .keys(stores.map(s => s.name))

stack.order(d3.stackOrderNone);
stack.offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);


var area = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    console.log('Data in X: ', d)
    return x(d.data.order_date);
  })
  .y0(function(d) {
    console.log('Data in Y0: ', d)
    return y(d[0]);
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    console.log('Data in Y1: ', d)
    return y(d[1]);
  });

// console.log('Area: ', area)
// console.log('StackData: ', stackData)
// console.log('Stack: ', stack(stackData))

// Will need to get max y-value */
const maxY = stackData.map(d => {
  const vals = d3.keys(d).map(k => k !== 'order_date' ? d[k] : 0);
  return d3.sum(vals);
});

// For any missing data, add a 0
const cleanData = stackData.map(d => {
  let existingStores = d3.keys(d);
  storeNames.forEach(n => {
    if (!existingStores.includes(n)) d[n] = 0
  })
  return d
});

// Update Scales
x.domain(d3.extent(rawData.map(d => new Date(d.order_date))));
// x.domain(d3.extent(stackData, function(d) {
//  return d.order_date;
// }));
y.domain([0, maxY]);

// Update axes
xAxisCall.scale(x);
xAxisGroup.call(xAxisCall)
yAxisCall.scale(y);
yAxisGroup.call(yAxisCall);

console.log('Data going to stack: ', cleanData);
const graph = g.selectAll('.store')
  .data(stack(cleanData));

console.log('CleanData: ', JSON.stringify(cleanData))
graph.enter().append('g')
  .attr('class', d => 'store')
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'area')
  .attr('d', area)
// .style('fill', d => color(d.key))
// .style('fill-opacity', 0.5)
/* } */
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="left-charts" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
      <div id="stacked-area"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Two potential issues I can see: using the `map` function to calculate `maxY` returns an array -- so I don't think your x domain is being set properly. Also, in the `area` function, the `d.data.order_date` is a string, not a Date object -- so the x scale is returning `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer as I could not still get it to display but was able to get rid of the NaN. The problem I found was that you never call the parseTime on the order_date in a number of places. This is also the reason why the x-axis ticks do not appear in your fiddle. Also the y-axis ticks do not appear. Which makes me think that the y domain is also not right. I did a console.log on maxY but it shows up with two values instead of one value. 
`data in maxY: 10044.86,10624.060000000001`

I feel that the plot is not appearing because the data is not presented in an appropriate format. Here is a fiddle where I have been able to get rid of the NaN but get values.

Here is the fiddle with the edits.

https://jsfiddle.net/coolakul/cxsx8e41/5/

```
var area = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    console.log('Data in X: ', parseTime(d.data.order_date))
    return parseTime(d.data.order_date);
  })
  .y0(function(d) {
    console.log('Data in Y0: ', d[0])
    return d[0];
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    console.log('Data in Y1: ', d[1])
    return d[1];
  });
```

Would love to discuss more but would need information of whether you are trying to implement a chart based on an example and also what is the final output you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Coola. I noticed in the area function you aren't passing the data in the area function to the x and y scales.  Is there a reason for that?  If I pass the values to the scales the error returns.

Comment: Hi walker. I noticed that as well. I believe that the area takes in numbers and in your code's case since the y domain is not set appropriately, it is unable to pass to the x and y scales. Although in my fiddle I am able to pass the x data after parsing the date for the x axis and the function as: `return x(parseTime(d.data.order_date));`

Comment: Ok, got it sorted out (kinda).  Here is a working fiddle. 
 I made a lot of edits, but it seems that the biggest issue is that the y.domain() didn't like the calculated value of `maxY` for some reason. 
 Changing that to `11000` seems to workhttps://jsfiddle.net/walkerl/8uxrxm0k/
Thanks for the tip on looking at the timeFormat.  I definitely had that goofed up as well.!

Comment: Walker the fiddle doesn't seem to show anything. May be you got the wrong one?